# capture the id of any button click

Tags: jquery, webforms

So, i have several buttons on ASP.NET WebForm, which fire off several ajax methods, to code behind WebMethod classes.

Several buttons effectively do the same thige, save, delete, update etc.

Is there a way to globally capture the firing of any button, grab it's id and then perform logic against it.

For example

```
 <button id='button1'/>
 <button id='button2'/>

 $('button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(e);
    });
```

this just responds with object object

***EDIT***
Should add that these buttons are in a ASP.NET repeater, so getting the Id as listed below produces the following:

buttonId_0

where 0 increments depending on the items being rendered in the repeater.

***EDIT***
So, ClientID="Static" sorted out the _0 numbering issue.

Comment: `alert()`ing objects doesn't give you anything helpful. Try `console.log(e)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need [this.id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert(this.id);// this refers to the current element clicked
});
```

---

Read [this keyword](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/fully-understanding-the-codethiscode-keyword--net-21117) and [this](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes You do the following.

```
 <button id='button1'/>
 <button id='button2'/>

 $('button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(this.id);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
alert($(this).attr('id')); // get the id attribute..
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:
demo : http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/645/

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });
```